# Serial connection - random byte at every read

Tags: serial-port, raspberry-pi

I'm writing a software for the RasPi, where I use serial communication. I wanted to test it, so I wrote a C# program which prints the output from the serial port.
I connected the RasPi to another computer with a USB->RS232 cable (The adafruit one). The input is fine, but before every input I receive a one byte long message, which is the same every time (unless I reboot the Pi, then that byte changes). Can I somehow remove it? Or just ignore it?

EDIT2:

If I send data from the PC to the Pi, then this random byte does not appear.

EDIT:

I even see that 0xf3 byte in Putty when I listen on the COM port

code that sends bytes:

```
char data[] = { 0x01, 0x01, 0x04, 0x06 };
write(m_device, (const void*)data, 4);
```

the output that I receive on the windows computer:

once

```
0xf3
```

then

```
0x01 0x01 0x04 0x06
```

Comment: Why is this tagged C++?

Comment: Show the code that's having the problem, and a sample of the output,please.

Comment: It's a random value.  You show 3F, will the one byte value be different after re-boot? Wondering if it is a comm delimiter.  I am assuming the Raspberry is in loop back mode.  If so, do you get the one byte when not looped back?

Comment: Yes, the value changes after a reboot. What do you mean under loop back mode? In my edit, I said that if I send data from Windows to RasPi, then this byte is not present

Comment: You say: 0xf3 then 0x01 0x01 0x04 0x06, and I see that is the 4 bytes is the data you are transmitting.   It may because this is not clear "but before every input I receive"  Do you mean Output from the Pi?  The term Input and Receive is confusing. Like is there a comma missing?  "but before every input, I receive

Comment: oh yes, it's pretty confusing, sorry :)
When sending from Pi -> Pc, before I receive the data (0x01 0x01 0x04 0x06), I got that 0xF3 byte. 

But that byte does not appear when I send from PC to Pi

Comment: I'm thinking it is a bug in Pi.  Does Pi have a built in compiler/interpreter? It may be that the comm Xmit routine is unintentionally doing this.  If it is consistent then you can just always ignore the first byte. If inconstant, then create a start delimiter for you transmissions from the Pi. I always used a plus + character to start any transmission to or from a serial device.  This simplifies the issues associated with asynchronous communications.  The more I think it through, the + is a very good idea for you.

Comment: I found something on the wiringPi's serial communication page. The users said that if they used a slower speed(e.g. 9600) then the leading byte disappears. I tried it and now it disappears. Could it be because I use the adafruit USB -> serial cable? The maker of the library wrote that if you want to talk thru USB serial you should use 9600 speed

Comment: If you are intending to distribute your app then you need to seriously consider diagnostics too. It is good idea for your app to monitor the ports RTS status to detect if there is connected device.  Be sure to have a handshake when connect to another device.  There should be a command  that your Pi app will always respond to.  Like +AT.  Think of it from the stand pot when there is a problem how do you determine if it is the Pi, your Pi all, or the connected terminal.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is the parity. You must set it even or odd. Try either setting.